# Procedure to compare 2 var count and set cursor in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a procedure where I am comparing two variables. I want to set if both variables values are equal then set cursor to true else false. I tried but its not working

Below is the query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_REJECTED_SITES_CR 
(
  P_CHANGEREQUESTID IN OUT TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO.CHANGE_REQUEST_ID%TYPE,
  OUTPUTTABLE OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)


AS 

VAR_ROW_COUNT        NUMBER;
VAR_REJECTED_COUNT    NUMBER;

BEGIN

VAR_ROW_COUNT     :=0;
VAR_REJECTED_COUNT     :=0;

OPEN OUTPUTTABLE FOR

select COUNT(*) INTO VAR_ROW_COUNT 
from TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO where CHANGE_REQUEST_ID = P_CHANGEREQUESTID;

select COUNT(*) INTO VAR_REJECTED_COUNT 
from TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO where CHANGE_REQUEST_ID = P_CHANGEREQUESTID and APPROVE_REJECT = 'Rejected';



IF VAR_ROW_COUNT = VAR_REJECTED_COUNT
THEN OUTPUTTABLE = TRUE;
ELSE
OUTPUTTABLE = FALSE;


END CHECK_REJECTED_SITES_CR;
```

**note** Also, I want to set those boolean value in cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL (before Oracle 23) does not have a `BOOLEAN` data-type; instead you need to use `1`/`0` or `'Y'`/`'N'` or `'TRUE'`/`'FALSE'`.

You can use `CASE` expressions and conditional aggregation:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_REJECTED_SITES_CR 
(
  P_CHANGEREQUESTID IN  TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO.CHANGE_REQUEST_ID%TYPE,
  OUTPUTTABLE       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS 
BEGIN
  OPEN OUTPUTTABLE FOR
    SELECT CASE
           WHEN COUNT(*)
                = COUNT(CASE APPROVE_REJECT WHEN 'Rejected' THEN 1 END)
           THEN 'TRUE'
           ELSE 'FALSE'
           END AS count_matches
    from   TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO
    where  CHANGE_REQUEST_ID = P_CHANGEREQUESTID;
END CHECK_REJECTED_SITES_CR;
/
```

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_cmp_emg_data_info (change_request_id, approve_reject) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Rejected' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Approved' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Rejected' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_match VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
  CHECK_REJECTED_SITES_CR(1, v_cur);
  FETCH v_cur INTO v_match;
  CLOSE v_cur;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1: ' || v_match);

  CHECK_REJECTED_SITES_CR(2, v_cur);
  FETCH v_cur INTO v_match;
  CLOSE v_cur;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2: ' || v_match);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
1: TRUE
2: FALSE
```

---

Alternatively, don't use cursors and just return the boolean:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_REJECTED_SITES_CR 
(
  P_CHANGEREQUESTID IN  TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO.CHANGE_REQUEST_ID%TYPE,
  O_MATCHES         OUT BOOLEAN
)
AS
  v_match NUMBER(1,0);
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*)
              = COUNT(CASE APPROVE_REJECT WHEN 'Rejected' THEN 1 END)
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END
  INTO   v_match
  FROM   TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO
  WHERE  CHANGE_REQUEST_ID = P_CHANGEREQUESTID;

  IF v_match = 1 THEN
    o_matches := TRUE;
  ELSE
    o_matches := FALSE;
  END IF;  
END CHECK_REJECTED_SITES_CR;
/
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_match BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  CHECK_REJECTED_SITES_CR(1, v_match);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1: ' || CASE WHEN v_match THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END);

  CHECK_REJECTED_SITES_CR(2, v_match);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2: ' || CASE WHEN v_match THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
1: TRUE
2: FALSE
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qRFhvOK5)

Comment: Getting eror as `Error(11,50): PL/SQL: ORA-12704: character set mismatch`

Comment: @hud It works for me (see the fiddle linked in the answer). Just providing an error message is not constructive as it doesn't tell us which bit of your code is "not working". If you want help debugging then you are going to need to provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data that replicates your error message.

Comment: @hud Also updated to not use a cursor and just directly return the boolean.

Comment: I am getting that character mismatch error still with your latest answer at line `COUNT(CASE APPROVE_REJECT WHEN 'Rejected' THEN 1 END)`

Comment: @hud It still works for me in the linked fiddle and you still haven't provided a `CREATE TABLE` statement that would give the information that might help to debug your problem. You can keep telling us that it "doesn't work" but that is not constructive behaviour; instead help us to help you by **YOU** [editing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78027175/edit) and providing the DDL statements for the table that will allow us to see what the character set is for the column and to replicate the problem.

Comment: You can always try `CASE WHEN APPROVE_REJECT  = 'Rejected' THEN 1 END` or, if the column is an `NVARCHAR2` then use an `NCHAR` literal like this: `CASE APPROVE_REJECT WHEN N'Rejected' THEN 1 END`. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pnKaukBC)

Comment: Thanks MT0, for this much help. Really appreciated.!

Answer (score 1):

You got something wrong; you can't set refcursor to *true* or *false*, that just doesn't make sense. Perhaps you wanted to include additional OUT parameter for that purpose? Something like this:

Sample table (so that procedure would compile):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tbl_cmp_emg_data_info
  2  AS
  3     SELECT 1 change_request_id, 'Rejected' approve_reject FROM DUAL;

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_rejected_sites_cr (
  2     p_changerequestid  IN     tbl_cmp_emg_data_info.change_request_id%TYPE,
  3     outputtable           OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  4     p_bool                OUT BOOLEAN)
  5  IS
  6     var_row_count       NUMBER;
  7     var_rejected_count  NUMBER;
  8  BEGIN
  9     SELECT COUNT (*), SUM (CASE WHEN approve_reject = 'Rejected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 10       INTO var_row_count, var_rejected_count
 11       FROM tbl_cmp_emg_data_info
 12      WHERE change_request_id = p_changerequestid;
 13
 14     IF var_row_count = var_rejected_count
 15     THEN
 16        p_bool := TRUE;
 17
 18        OPEN outputtable FOR SELECT *
 19                               FROM tbl_cmp_emg_data_info
 20                              WHERE approve_reject = 'Rejected';
 21     ELSE
 22        p_bool := FALSE;
 23
 24        OPEN outputtable FOR SELECT *
 25                               FROM tbl_cmp_emg_data_info
 26                              WHERE approve_reject <> 'Rejected';
 27     END IF;
 28  END;
 29  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     rc      SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3     l_bool  BOOLEAN;
  4  BEGIN
  5     check_rejected_sites_cr (2, rc, l_bool);
  6
  7     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_Line (
  8        CASE WHEN l_bool THEN 'Returned value = TRUE' ELSE 'Returned value = FALSE' END);
  9  END;
 10  /
Returned value = FALSE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT: without refcursor]**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_rejected_sites_cr (
  2     p_changerequestid  IN     tbl_cmp_emg_data_info.change_request_id%TYPE,
  3     p_bool                OUT BOOLEAN)
  4  IS
  5     var_row_count       NUMBER;
  6     var_rejected_count  NUMBER;
  7  BEGIN
  8     SELECT COUNT (*), SUM (CASE WHEN approve_reject = 'Rejected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  9       INTO var_row_count, var_rejected_count
 10       FROM tbl_cmp_emg_data_info
 11      WHERE change_request_id = p_changerequestid;
 12
 13     IF var_row_count = var_rejected_count
 14     THEN
 15        p_bool := TRUE;
 16     ELSE
 17        p_bool := FALSE;
 18     END IF;
 19  END;
 20  /

Procedure created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_bool  BOOLEAN;
  3  BEGIN
  4     check_rejected_sites_cr (2, l_bool);
  5
  6     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_Line (
  7        CASE WHEN l_bool THEN 'Returned value = TRUE' ELSE 'Returned value = FALSE' END);
  8  END;
  9  /
Returned value = FALSE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: This is not what i want.. I want that if value of both count is same then true else false.. with your query, I am getting whole outputtable

Comment: I want to reurn `p_bool` value

Comment: So adjust that code so that it returns **only** P_BOOL and omit OUTPUTTABLE.

Comment: ok, can u do in ur proc and update it if possible

Comment: Sure; have a look at edited answer.

Comment: I am not getting the output

Comment: Did you enable serveroutput? If not DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE won't display anything.